Python - read xlsx file then append a string to the specific data
I have a xlsx file (test.xlsx) and it looks like this:

What I want to do is to use pandas to read this file then if the Phone column is yes, I want to append " - mobile" after "yes" then create a new xlsx file something like:

So, I create list to pet all the values in it. I tried like this:
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
l = df.get('Phone')
list = []

for value in df.index:
   if value.isnull():
      list.append(' ')
   else:
      list.append(value+' - mobile')

I want to add nothing or a space to list if the cell is empty but I don't know how to check if it's nan.
Any help will be appliciated. Thank you

df.loc[df['Phone'] == 'yes', 'Type'] = 'yes - mobile' ?

You don't have to check if the value is missing because missing values will automatically be ignored (this is quite annoying in some cases, like if you want them to be considered when calculating some statistics). So all you have to do, as ifly6 pointed out, is:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data= { 'Name':['John','Jane','Bob','Cathy','Will'], 'Phone': ['yes',np.nan,np.nan,'yes',np.nan]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.loc[df['Phone'] == 'yes', 'Type'] = 'yes - mobile'
print(df)

